# Using websockets for Android chat

Tags: android, websocket, chat, real-time

I'm using WebSockets to allow for real time chat within my android application. When the app is not active and the user recieves a message,  GCM works to turn  the websockets service on in the background and reenable real time chatting,.

I have read concerns about WebSockets and battery life but if I use GCM to turn on the WebSockets only when the user has a new message to respond to, is this a viable solution to allow real time chatting?

Answer (score 2):

No I don't think so .GCM are not 100% reliable.
Their documentation says:

GCM usually delivers messages immediately after they are sent. However, this might not always be possible. For example, if the platform is Android, the device could be turned off, offline, or otherwise unavailable. Or the sender itself might request that messages not be delivered until the device becomes active by using the delay_while_idle flag. Finally, GCM might intentionally delay messages to prevent an application from consuming excessive resources and negatively impacting battery life.

When this happens, GCM will store the message and deliver it as soon as it's feasible. While this is fine in most cases, there are some applications for which a late message might as well never be delivered. For example, if the message is an incoming call or video chat notification, it will only be meaningful for a small period of time before the call is terminated. Or if the message is an invitation to an event, it will be useless if received after the event has ended.

So you can use GCM to reconnect to the webSockets if the client is not connected,but once the connection is made ,then all the communication should be on the socket itself.

Comment: That is exactly how I set it up. GCM is used only when the device is not connected through WebSockets otherwise all communication goes through WebSockets